# A thermally conductive gap filler does not conduct the heat as expected. Where does the heat go?

Tags: thermodynamics, home-experiment, thermal-conductivity

I have a mug warmer, which is a hot plate that I've measured heats up to 56C.
It came with a mug with a flat bottom, which gets its contents warmed up to about 53C after some minutes.
My understanding of the sytem is that the 56C of the hot plate is a boundary condition that would force the mug to eventually reach that same temperature if there was no heat lost to the environment. But of course there is some heat loss, which is why the mug stabilizes at about 53C.

Now, I have added to the hot plate a 5mm layer of a compressible [thermally conductive gap filler](https://au.mouser.com/ProductDetail/laird-performance-materials/a15340-01/?qs=3IuyYncJTQHGivET%252bac4WQ%3D%3D), which is normally used to fill the gap between a heat-generating electronic component and a heatsink; my goal being to be able to use mugs with a non-flat bottom, like any off-the-shelf ceramic mug, while still having good thermal contact.

The problem is, I found that somehow the gap filler is not transferring the heat as much as I expected **even when there is full contact**, and I don't understand why.

The surface of the gap filler gets as hot as the hot plate: 56C.
However, even **the flat-bottomed mug on top of that flat gap filler gets only to 41C**, no matter how long I wait.
As far as I can tell, every surface here is flat and having good contact.
So, how to explain the fact that just introducing the gap filler lowers (so much!) the maximum temperature reached by the same mug? It's as if the filler is sinking part of the heat, which makes no sense - right? So, where does the heat "go"? What am I missing?

### Adding some detail:

The mug is about 10 cm high and 8 cm in diameter, so its side surface is about 251 $cm^2$. It is not double-walled, so it gets hot in every case.
The gap filler is a circle, 5 mm high and 5.2 cm in diameter covering the hot plate, so its side surface is about 8 $cm^2$.

[image: The mug warmer, gap filler and mug on top]

Comment: Try varying layers of gap filler.  I suspect that your gap filler has only a moderately good thermal conductivity, which means that there is a large temperature drop across the gap filler.  This can be verified by noting that thicker layes of gap filler produce lower temperatures.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, the top surface of the filler reaches 56C, just like the hot plate itself.

Comment: My question is related to how fast the filler can conduct heat, not what it's top temperature is when it is not under a heat load.

Comment: You said "temperature drop", so I answered that (0). If you mean thermal conductivity of the filler, it is 1.2 W/(m*K) (the data sheet is linked)

Comment: The filler can't conduct heat with a zero temperature drop because the driving force for heat transfer is a temperature difference.  It shouldn't take you much effort to try my suggested experiment in order to verify if your filler has a thermal conductivity problem.  Of course, if you prefer, you could just keep arguing with me and never find out.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow or we're understanding each other. AFAIK, "driving force for heat transfer" is the 2nd law of thermodynamics, not "temperature difference" - but I'll be grateful for any material to educate myself. I tried your experiment, and the temperature drop across 4 layers of filler is about 5C - though I am not sure how much of a red herring is that, given the real problem that was already found by @SalomonSlow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, where does the heat "go"?

Into the surrounding environment of course!

Sounds like your hot-plate is temperature controlled. (I.e., it's surface temp will never exceed 56C.) If that's the case, then you should expect that the the temperature of the mug to be less if you put any kind of insulating material between the mug and the hot plate: Slowing the heat flow will not increase the temperature of the hot plate, but instead will slow the rate at which the temperature control allows heat *in* to the hot plate and eventually, to the mug.

My *guess* is that your "gap filler" is a better conductor than the air that it displaces, but it doesn't conduct heat as well as direct, surface-to-surface contact when you use that one special mug.

Comment: How are you measuring the temperatures?

Comment: Interesting point. I assumed that 56C is just the maximum temperature that can be reached by the power source, but if there is any kind of temperature control / "throttling", things would change. I'll try some disassembling or measuring the consumed power in each case.

Comment: @nielsnielsen, with a digital thermometer in contact with each of the surfaces.

Comment: Good thermal filler materials come with datasheets that tell you exactly what their thermal conductivity is. And it is very common for it to be a lot better than air, but a lot worse than the things they are stuffed between.

Comment: @ThePhoton, the data sheet is linked in the question. The thermal conductivity is 1.2 W/(m*K).

Comment: @SolomonSlow, looking at the power consumption made things clear: there is some temperature-dependent power cycling going on, kind of a slow PWM. So, looks like the filler doesn't conduct heat fast enough, and the hot plate starts the power cycling to avoid overheating, which breaks my assumption of the constant temperature as a boundary condition.

Comment: Interestingly, even with a cold mug there is some power cycling, which means that the mug warmer's design is more concerned with avoiding overheating at the plate than with heating the mug the fastest. I didn't expect that for such a "toy" thing!

Answer (score 2):

Heat may be lost in any number of places other than directly to the contents in the mug.

- To the air surrounding the sidewalls of the gap-filler. Your experiment with the original flat-bottomed mug does not include this loss. To minimize (remove) this part, you should also insulate around the edges of the gap filler. Given the thickness of the filler pad, this is likely the greatest loss.
- To the side walls of the mug itself, whereby it then goes to the air surrounding the mug. This loss will be evident when you change to different mugs.

In your system, the heater likely has a limit to supply a fixed power (to avoid blowing up). This is a limit to the heat flow (current flow) for the case without and with the filler.

The two pictures are below, with $h$ as heater (fixed source), $f$ as conduction through the filler, $l$ as loss from the sidewalls, $m$ as conduction into the mug, and $c$ as conduction/convection into the contents.

[image: Pictures of systems with heat flows.]

Comment: Re, "In your system, you supply the same fixed heat flow." I bet not. If it were true, then the product would be dangerous—quite likely to start a fire if somebody accidentally covered it while it was switched on, and then walked away. I _strongly_ suspect that the temperature of the hot plate is controlled by a thermostat. If that was the case, then it would correspond to a constant _voltage_ source in your analogy, not a constant current source.

Comment: The constant voltage source may also have a limit to power output.

Comment: I am not sure I follow the analogy. The surface of the gap filler where the mug rests also gets to 56C, which if I understand correctly breaks the analogy.
Also, the mug walls of course get hot in every case, including the no-filler case. So, I don't see how adding the negligible side surface of the filler can amount to much. (should I add a picture?)

Comment: Added picture and geometry details. The side surface of the mug is ~251 cm2, while the side surface of the filler is ~8 cm2.

Comment: Well certainly with the picture showing how thick the gap filler is in relation to the system, the answer can be framed with greater detail.

Answer (score 2):

Gap fillers for use in semiconductor-heatsink junctions are typically filling gaps that are of order 0.5mm or *less* in thickness. At 8mm, that gap filler layer is far, far too thick. As such it is interfering with heat transfer, not enhancing it, by leaking heat out through its thick side wall. The surface area of the leak path is, as you say, about 8cm^2. Compared to the surface area of the top surface of the gap filler slab- 21cm^2- it is significant!

Comment: In geometrical terms, it's true that the side surface is not negligible compared to the top surface. 
But in heatsinking terms, I don't see how the side surface (interfacing to air) can hold a candle to the top surface (interfacing to the cup). Particularly when taking into account that, without the filler, the cup gets enough heat to stabilize 0.5 L at 51 C.